# How to fix 401 - unauthorized - when testing spring rest API secured with google oauth2 via postman - roles in DB

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, postman, google-oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I was following this articles
https://www.javachinna.com/spring-boot-angular-10-user-registration-oauth2-social-login-part-1/

https://www.javachinna.com/spring-boot-angular-10-user-registration-oauth2-social-login-part-2/

I want to test the spring endpoints via postman, and setup below and getting token, but not sure of the roles. The roles are in DB

***How can I test my rest api using postman***

My endpoint is like below

```
@GetMapping("/todos")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public List<CourseDTO> list(@CurrentUser LocalUser user) {
        System.out.println(user);
        return myService.findAll();
    }
```

Websecurity config

> .antMatchers("/", "/error", "/api/all", "/api/auth/**", "/oauth2/**",
> "/index.html", "/*.js", "/*.js.map", "/*.css", "/assets/img/*.png",
> "/favicon.ico").permitAll()

though I tried `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/admin/todo/**").hasRole("ADMIN")`

> But getting 401 unauthorized -   "message": "Full authentication is
> required to access this resource",

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set it like this and then retry :

```
grant_type=client_credentials
```

Comment: if I change grant type to client credentials...I cant generate new access token. so not working. Did you try?